# Create frequency table multiple variables-different number of rows

Tags: r, frequency

I am new to R and apologize if this is a basic question.  I have a data.frame of which all 14 variables are factors.  I have 11 measured variables that are 1 of 10 different levels, but not all variables include all levels.  I want to create a frequency table with the measured variables as the columns and the levels as the rows for all 11 measured variables.

The structure of my data.frame is below:

```
Publication: Factors.. 2 levels
Year: Factors... 5 levels
Energy Type: Factors... 6 levels
AQ: Factors... 3 levels
CA:  Factors... 9 levels
CCM: Factors... 8 levels
FFR: Factors: 5 levels
```

(my table doesn't format properly in display window)

I want to achieve a frequency table including all measured variables (e.g. AQ, CA, CCM, FFR) as the columns and the levels as the rows- inserting NA where a variable doesn't include a particular level.

I first tried creating multiple tables and then using rbind- but not all measured variables include all levels- so the table is inaccurate.  I tried rbind.fill which requires inputs to be data.frames (as opposed to tables), but this led with difficulties in converting the tables to data.frames...  I also tried reshaping and casting the data, but I don't think reshape is the solution to my question...

I appreciate any help is the best way to approach this problem.
Michelle

Here is an example of my table:

```
Publication         Year    AQ  CCM CA
Bangor Daily News   2006    No  No  No
Bangor Daily News   2006    No  No  R1
Bangor Daily News   2006    No  No  C1
Bangor Daily News   2006    No  No  No
Bangor Daily News   2006    No  No  C1
```

Comment: It would be easier if you provide an small example dataset and your expected result

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the expected result:

#### data

```
dat1 <- structure(list(Publication = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
Year = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L
), .Label = c("2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008"), class = "factor"), 
AQ = structure(c(5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "factor"), CA = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("b", "c", 
"d", "e", "f"), class = "factor"), CCM = structure(c(4L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("d", "e", 
"f", "h"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Publication", 
"Year", "AQ", "CA", "CCM"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Create unique list of elements from the `measured variables`

```
Un <- unique(unlist(dat1[,3:5]))
```

Use `table` to get the frequency of each columns after setting the levels to levels of `Un`

```
res <- sapply(dat1[,3:5], function(x) table(factor(x, levels=levels(Un))))
res[!res] <- NA # change 0's to NA
res 
#   AQ CA CCM
# a  1 NA  NA
# b  1  1  NA
# c  1  1  NA
# d  4  4   2
# e  3  1   1
# f NA  3   2
# h NA NA   5
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Akrun.  Your final table is what I'm after.  I have a question regarding the "...=structure(c(1L,1L,1L,2L,2L....)" part of your first statement.  I have 452 records- does your method require listing the entire structure? I tried entering the values (levels) that exist for each variable, but get an error message saying the "object" doesn't exist for at least one of the levels.

Comment: @mdebartolo.  I used `dput(dat1)` to get that structure for easy reproducibility.  You can read your dataset using `read.table/read.csv` etc..